# How to disable "changing a repeating event" dialog in Mac calendar?

Tags: macos, terminal, ical

I have a number of repeating events in Calendar (formerly iCal).

I often make changes to individual ones on-the-go, but every time it asks me this:

[image]

**How can I make the default behaviour change a single event without that dialog appearing?**

I suspect there could be a Terminal command I can run.

BONUS: Then, if I want to edit the series, can I still use the `Get Info` interface?

Comment: Interesting idea. You want to basically never be asked to change all future events? (or are you proposing a script that could automate severing one instance of a repeating event, saving the details and then making a stand alone instance that's not part of the recurring pattern?)

Comment: @bmike, I think either would work — the message is an annoyance 95% of the time for me

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it cannot be settled up using CLI settings

> defaults  read com.apple.iCal

have no option to change default behaviour. But you can find useful a scripting with AppleScript